# How to read data from server.js to client.js and save to another variable before loading it?

Tags: reactjs, server, fetch, client

I am implementing a react app that integrates with Microsoft login page.I want to read the clientId from server.js and load into the client page.
Below is the code:
**But the clientId is always undefined.**
Can someone please help in identifying my mistake?
/server/server.ts

```
app.get("/api/config/", async function (request: Request, response: Response) {
    const clientId = "abc-djfjgjg-gjjj-495"
    const config = {
        "clientId": clientId
    }
    response.status(200).send({
        ...config
    });
});
```

client/src/App.tsx

```
import { loginRequest, protectedResources } from "./config/config";

const App = () => {
  const authRequest = {
    ...loginRequest,
};

return (
      <>
       <MsalAuthenticationTemplate 
            interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect} 
            authenticationRequest={authRequest}
        >
        <HeaderComponent />
        <div className="bodycontainer">
          <MainPage/>
        </div>
        <FooterComponent/>
        </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

client/src/config.tsx

```
let clientId : any ;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/config/");
        const data = await response.json();
        clientId = data
}
//CALL FETCH DATA TO GET CONFIG DETAILS FROM SERVER
fetchData()
console.log("What is clientId" + clientId) // always returned as undefined

export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx', 
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xx',
        redirectUri: '/', 
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
        clientCapabilities: ['CP1'],
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level : any, message : any, containsPii: any) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};


export const protectedResources = {
    api: {
        firstEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        dashboardEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        scopes: ['api://xxxx-xxxxxx-x-xxxx/access_via_approle_assignments'],
    },
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [...protectedResources.api.scopes],
};

export const appRoles = {
    Railway: "Railway"
}
```

index.tsx

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalConfig } from "./config/config";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
              <App />
      </MsalProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```